# Secondary click in Lion with two fingers OR bottom-right corner click

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, system-settings

I just did a clean install of Lion on my 2010 MBP. It seems as though in the system preferences for the built-in trackpad, I have the option of setting the secondary click gesture to "Click or tap with two fingers", "Click in bottom right corner", or "Click in bottom left corner".

Previous to this fresh install, I had simply upgraded from Snow Leopard where I had been able to initiate a secondary click *either* by a two-finger tap *or* a click in the bottom right corner. That setting was preserved when I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion. When I simply did a fresh install of Lion, it's now either one or the other. Not both.

Does anyone know how I can get the "both" behavior back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think it's possible to do that without a third party solution. Two popular applications that allow you to tweak the touchpad and mouse are [Magic Prefs](http://magicprefs.com/) and [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/).

Answer (score 14):

**Run the following six commands, by pasting them into Terminal.app.** You can paste all six lines all at once. *(the last two lines aren't required on older versions of OS X, but there's no harm including them)* Remember to **press the return key**:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick -int 2

defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadRightClick -bool true

defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.trackpadCornerClickBehavior -int 1

defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.enableSecondaryClick -bool true

defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick -int 2

defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadRightClick -bool true
```

Important: now **reboot your Mac.**

When you log back in, you will be able to right-click both with a two-finger tap, and by clicking in the bottom right-hand corner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This also works on Yosemite

Comment: I used Charlesisms method above but on 10.10.3 this doesn't seem to work anymore, defaulting to only the touchpad criteria set last in the terminal. Can anyone confirm this method is no longer working please? I'm new to Mac and could be doing it wrong, but I think I executed the commands correctly. Using BetterTouchTool I have managed to enable both but was hoping to do so with less clutter!

Comment: @MattBaines Hmm, still working on my 10.10.3 Mac. I can still use both on my machine, and I assume I used the same commands when I upgraded the OS. Did you try using "killall cfprefsd" after entering the commands?

Comment: Doesn't work in macOS Sierra

Comment: @johnmast, Thanks for the heads-up. I have added two new lines, which should work for Sierra.

Comment: I confirm that the above updated solutions works on macOS Sierra. Thanks @Charlesism

Comment: Does this mean that if I am on El Capitan or Sierra, I still need all six of these commands? Or only the last two? Also, does this only work for the bottom right corner? I was hoping to get it set to use the top right corner (easier to reach with your thumb while typing).

Comment: @user5359531 I haven't tried, but the last two would probably do fine. Not that there's much harm in using them all. All that the commands do is write new settings to a few plist files in ~/Library/Preferences and if the OS doesn't use a few of them it's no harm done

Comment: This solution works on MacOS High Sierra. Beautiful!

Comment: Unfortunately not working on Mojave.

Comment: Has worked for me, even on the dumpster fire that is MacOS Catalina.

Comment: does still work on m1 Macs (Ventura13.2beta)
Thanks